# Why doesn't my function return values but it works if I use print?

Tags: python

I'm learning function() and writing a practice.

Nothing returned after I entered an integer.

```
def collatz(number):
    if number%2==0:
        return (number//2)
    if number%2==1:
        return (3*number+1)

userInput=int(input('Enter an integer: '))
collatz(userInput)
```

But if I replace "return" statement with "print", it will work. I've seen an example using "return" statement in the function to return different strings. Can "return" only be used to return string? Must I use "print" If I need to return a calculated value? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `print(collatz(userInput))` or `result = collatz(userInput); print(result)`

Comment: "return" doesn't mean "display". "return" sends value from function to main code so you can assign it to variable. If you want to see value from this variable then you have to use `print()` to display it.

Comment: Thanks! But what's the use of "return"? If we need to print after using return, why don't people just use "print" in the function? @furas

Comment: they don't use "print" because they can still use it outside function like `print(collatz(userInput))` or they can use returned value in other calculation like `result = 2+ collatz(userInput)` . It makes function more universal. But if you use function only to display result then you can use "print" inside function - all depends on you.

Comment: if function returns value then you can use create tests - like `print(  collatz(1) == 4 )` . This way you can check if function gives correct results and you don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling your function but you are not using returned value:

```
collatz(userInput)
```

you can save result of return in variable and then print it

```
value = collatz(userInput)
print (value)
```

or directly print it:

```
print (collatz(userInput))
```

full code:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number%2==0:
        return (number//2)
    if number%2==1:
        return (3*number+1)

userInput=int(input('Enter an integer: '))
print (collatz(userInput))
```

Comment: Thank you~ I have one confusion. If people need to print after using return, why don't people just use print? what is the use of "return"?

Comment: The return statement causes your function to exit and hand back a value to its caller. The point of functions in general is to take in inputs and return something. The return statement is used when a function is ready to return a value to its caller.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning a value, but this value isn't being printed because you haven't asked for it to be printed.

Try something like this:

```py
def foo():
    return 5

print(foo())
```